# Egyptian number system?

Tags: mathematics

How did ancient Egyptians know that they have to choose the symbols for multiple of 10 in their Egyptian number system, since at that time hindu-arabic system was not there and no one knows what is 1,2,3,...or 10?

Comment: Somebody write please!

Comment: See [Egyptian numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_numerals).

Comment: But I am asking after reading Wikipedia

Comment: What does it mean "at that time hindu-arabic system was not there and no one knows what is 1,2,3,...or 10?" Of course the hindu-arabic numerals were not yet available... thus, they used different numerals (symbols for numbers). Ancient Greeks used difefrent numerals, ancient Romans dufferent, and so on.

Comment: how do we know that the Egyptians counting symbols correspond to power of 10 in today's language

Comment: In what sense ?

Comment: We know how to read Ancient Egyptian language (see [Rosetta Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) and [Champollion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Champollion)).

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus for an example of an A.E. explanation of how to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Egyptian language, like most languages of the world, has a counting system based implicitly on base 10. This is much older than any system of mathematical notation. When the Egyptians began writing numbers they reflected the counting system which existed in their language.